# How to access Magento 2 shipping & cart total in custom sidebar?

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I am building a custom Magento 2 **right sidebar module**. It will bring **sidebar panel** from right when a **new item is added**.

I can access all **cart items** data from **default js modules** except **Shipping Total** & **Grant Total** in my **phtml** file.

You can go through my code shared on GitHub by visiting this URL:

> https://github.com/biswajitpaul01/mage2-cart-sidebar

Can anyone suggest how can I get those in my `view/frontend/templates/cart/sidebar-minicart.phtml` file?

Thanks in advanced.